# Position the siblings when using scaling with transform property

Tags: javascript, css, css-transforms

I am implementing the CSS transform property over a division and have a use case of moving the siblings which are located next to it as per the scaling.

I tried adjusting the positions but did not work and thought this is how the transform functions. I might be wrong so want to give a one more try here.

```css
.parent{
  display:flex;
}
.childA{
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 20rem;
  background: lightblue;
}
.childA:hover {
  transform: scale(5);
  transform-origin:top left;
  z-index:0;
}
.childB {
  border: solid 1px;
  color:white;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: red;
  z-index:1 /*Not sure why I had to do this too*/
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
   <div class='childA'>Child A scales</div>
   <div class='childB'>I want to move when scaled</div>
</div>
```

Please take a look at this playground where the child element is just staying there but I need it to move towards the right
https://codepen.io/frank-underwood/pen/jOOmLJO?editors=1100

Comment: I am facing different issues now, here is the issue raised! @temani-afif
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58563689/scroll-only-the-div-horizontally-vertically-when-transformed-to-a-scale-and-po

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.parent{
  display:flex;
}
.childA{
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 20rem;
  background: lightblue;
}
.childA:hover {
  transform: scale(5);
  transform-origin:top left;
  z-index:0;
}

.childA:hover + .childB {
  transform: translateX(calc(22rem * 4));
}
.childB {
  border: solid 1px;
  color:white;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: red;
  z-index:1
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
   <div class='childA'>Child A scales</div>
   <div class='childB'>I want to move when scaled</div>
</div>
```

I'm not sure how much you're wanting to move it, or where.. Here is code to make it move on the hover of your scaling element.  I'm using the adjacent CSS combinator to make this happen.  When you're hovering ChildA, the adjacent ChildB can be given a set of properties.

As for why you had to put a z-index on `.childB` was because transforms create a new stacking context.  Even though `.childA` comes before `.childB` in your HTML, the transform essentially brings `.childA` to a new layer.  Therefore, you have to set `.childB`'s z-index.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context

Here's some reading about stacking context.  It's really important to understand how these work and what creates new ones.

**edit** You can calc the translate based off the element your hovering and it will consistently move.  I added 2rem to the width because you have 1rem of padding on either side.  22rem * 4 instead of 5 because scale(1) = 22rem.

Comment: I like this approach however, I always need `childB` to the right of `childA` keeping the zoom on `childA`

Comment: Ahh okay.  The easiest solution probably is the other answer.  I'll tinker with the transforms and try to get you a consistent solution using the more performant method.

Comment: The other solution with widths? In that case, I need to calculate all the child elements of parent A and increase the widths and heights accordingly and the responsive breakpoints come in. 
But if that is the only possible way, I think I have no other option :/

Comment: I updated my answer.  You can do a calc that's based off the element you're hovering.  Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: I cannot see the childB with the calculation provided but I tried random tests and found 83% is getting used for 0.5 scale so, for 1.5, I need to set translateX to be 83% and for 2 it is 166%. I am not sure what kinda logic is this.

Comment: Did you run the code in my example? You'll have to fullscreen it. It pushes it really far over.

Comment: I need to adjust the translateX for every scale right?!

Comment: Yes. 22rem * scaleValue - 1

Comment: Awesome! This looks like a feasible solution to my application. Does it have to deal with the viewports? o.O

Comment: No it shouldn't have anything to do with the viewport.

Comment: You're absolutely right! It has no deal with the viewport. Thanks, Brett! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to adjust your html structure you can easily do this:

```css
.parent{
  display:flex;
}
.leftDiv{
  background:yellow
}
.childA{
  padding: 1rem;
  background: lightblue;
  position:relative;
}
.childA:hover {
  transform: scale(2);
  transform-origin:top left;
  z-index:0;
}
.childA:hover .childB {
  transform: scale(0.5);
  transform-origin:top left;
}
.childB {
  border: solid 1px;
  color:white;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: red;
  position:absolute;
  left:100%;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  white-space:nowrap;

}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='leftDiv'>I will just stay here</div>
 <div class='childA'>Child A scales
   <div class='childB'>I want to move when scaled</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great, so the ratio of the child will be `1/scale` right? But unfortunately, I am using the display grid for these columns and can't couple them together and need to be as siblings from `.parent`

Comment: @vam yes it's `1/scale` and you can always adjust your HTML like you want. If you aren't able to do then you are doing something wrong even if you want to consider grid or flexbox.

Comment: yeah, I just realized there would not be any complexities except the certain rework in my CSS properties. Thanks Temani for the approach though! :)

Comment: I wish I could select 2 answers but that is the first approach I got to know and does not require me to modify the HTML. Sorry about that Temani! :/

Comment: @vam no problem, the important thing is that we have two useful anwser to be used in case someone face the same issue. The accepted mark is only a detail.

Comment: I totally, agree with you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Transform affect like absolute position, so you increase width and with calc method you can set how times it increas;

```css
.parent{
  display:flex;
}
.childA{
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 20rem;
  background: lightblue;
}
.childA:hover {
  width: calc(20rem * 5);/*here you can change 5*/
  transform-origin:top left;
}
.childB {
  border: solid 1px;
  color:white;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
 <div class='childA'>Child A scales</div>
 <div class='childB'>I want to move when scaled</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This will work, but transforms are done in the composite stage of browser rendering.  Changing the width will affect performance because it will have to repaint.  Always try to use transforms or opacity if possible for modifying styles.

Comment: Yeah, you're right but I am using the scale property specifically to have a zoom effect but with this, I need change the child elements styling as well right

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  Depending on how you're wanting it to move with the scale can affect the approach.